# How to use Android activity fragment from other packages?

Tags: android, android-activity, package, apk, fragment

I have just begun development on Android ICS.
I have a requirement to reuse some activity fragments inside my application.
For example, when I want to write a 'setup wizard' application, I need to reuse the WIFI setting activity fragment in my own APK.
But it seems that activity fragment can only be used within the same package(APK).
Does any one know how to deal with this?

Thanks a lot.

-Robin

Answer (score 0):

> But it seems that activity fragment can only be used within the same package(APK)

Correct.

> I need to reuse the WIFI setting activity fragment in my own APK

I do not know if your app can have all the permissions necessary to do all the things the Setting app's WiFi screen does. That being said, you are welcome to [browse the source code for Settings](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings) and pull out what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I don't think copy code is a good idea. Since some setting made of phone/call is stored in runtime variables inside their own process.

Comment: @Robin: You act as though you have a choice.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have one. Technically, maybe I can start an activity group in my fragment. And then start another activity/fragment by that activity group. It might be complex and ugly, and not verified.

Comment: @Robin: "And then start another activity/fragment by that activity group" -- fortunately, this is not possible, for obvious security reasons. Most likely, you will need to simply cut out this functionality from your app.

Comment: That's possible, since I am making my own firmware. I have system UID.